# How to put texture on procedural generated cloud

Tags: texturing, node-editor, geometry-nodes

I have the procedural generated cloud with nodes and I want to achieve effect like graffiti painting on it so I want to put texture on the surface of the cloud. I have tried shrinkwrap but it won't work. Is there any way to get it?[image]

Comment: Hello ! How is the cloud generated exactly ?

Comment: @Gorgious Using default cube with shaders from screen applied, noise texture and less than

Comment: Okay then you'll have to use a 3D texture for instance since the modifiers like shrinkwrap won't be able to access any of the displaced vertices nor the volumetric info. For instance try to plug the color output of your noise texture into the color input of the volume BSDF and see what happens

Comment: @Gorgious Then I can see the cloud become colorful https://imgur.com/a/a2vRWkm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gorgious mentioned, you can do this by using the Color Input of the Principled Volume Shader. Since you are using a base cube for your volume, I recommend using *generated* texture coordinates, and *Box* projection for the image. The image I used in the example has an alpha, so I used that as the mix factor between the image and white before connecting to the color input:

[image: GraffittiVolume]

Comment: Is there a way how to make it more stable and independent from view angle? If I go around to sharp enough corner it's impossible to see anything, I understand it's ok for this setup but maybe it is possible to improve it? https://imgur.com/a/csDw2SS https://imgur.com/a/nAY5wah

Comment: If there is, I don't know how. - to do that I think you would have to find a way to calculate the exterior surface of the volume (cloud) and then map it to some kind of texture coordinate system that is compatible with both procedural and uniform (image) textures. If someone knows how, I would _love_ to know.